# automatically create db in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db

I was wondering if Zend has any way to automatically construct a database from model declarations. I could not find any documentation on the matter. I'm talking now from the point of view of someone who has experience in Python, where both Django ORM and SQLAlchemy provide a way to automatically create all database tables by some simple introspection of the models. Is something like this available for Zend or do I have to manually create my database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install the Doctrine2 module for ZF2: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule

You'll be forced to write entities in the Doctrine way, though. Once you created your entities you'll then have to use a console command to generate the SQL and inject the tables like so:

```
orm:schema-tool:create
```

Whenever you change something in your entities you then have to run:

```
orm:schema-tool:update
```

Comment: Not sure what's going on with that dev documentation - but it looks like ZF1 code?

Comment: Now that you mention it it does look a bit off. But this has namespaces in it. Was it possible just like that in zf1? I tought you had to use workarounds to get that behavior?